# Disable .babelrc inheritance

Tags: babeljs

How do I force babel NOT to look at the parent directory for `.babelrc`?

- I have two `.babelrc` files: `./a/.babelrc` and `./a/example/.babelrc`.
- I am running `babel` in `./a/example` path.
- `./a/.babelrc` defines a plugin “lodash".
- I do not want to use this plugin when executing babel in `./a/example`

I have tried setting `./a/example/.babelrc` to:

```
{
    "stage": 0,
    "plugins": []
}
```

However, running `babel` in `./a/example` path still uses "lodash" plugin.

```
$ pwd
/a/example
$ cat ./.babelrc
{
    "stage": 0,
    "plugins": []
}
$ cat ./../.babelrc
{
    "stage": 0,
    "plugins": [
        "lodash"
    ]
}
$ babel ./src/
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/a/node_modules/babel-plugin-lodash/node_modules/lodash'
    [..]
$ babel --babelrc ./.babelrc ./src/
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/a/node_modules/babel-plugin-lodash/node_modules/lodash'
    [..]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an undocumented property called `breakConfig`. Set `breakConfig` to `true` to disable config inheritance.

This behaviour is going to change in 6.x. In 6.x Babel will break on the first `.babelrc` it finds. `extends` property is going to be used to explicitly name other `.babelrc` files to inherit from.

Comment: Is there an issue referencing those changes for v6 @Gajus?

Comment: @JMM, no. I have learned about it from chatting with the author.

Comment: .@Gajus OK thanks, that's what I figured :) That really ought to be in the 6.0 issue though.